Inserting images in the footer
I have a template file, it contains controls for inserting pictures. The picture is inserted normally into the body of the document and the first card into the footer too, but when I insert the second picture into the footer which is located in the table cells, my file breaks
Error when opening
Moreover, the error shows in the header, but I don’t even add anything there
Start inserting an image
IEnumerable<SdtElement> sdtBlockList = body.Descendants<SdtElement>();
IEnumerable<SdtElement> sdtBlockFooterList = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.SelectMany(x => x.Footer.Descendants<SdtElement>());

string tagKey = ((TeoTagModel<(string, byte[])>)value).TagKey;

var footerParts = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts;

var sdtBlocks = sdtBlockList.Where(sdt => sdt.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.Value == tagKey);
var sdtBlockFooter = sdtBlockFooterList.Where(sdt => sdt.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.Value == tagKey);

var footer = footerParts
.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Footer.Descendants<SdtElement>()
.FirstOrDefault(a => a.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.Value == tagKey) != null);

if (sdtBlocks.Any())
{
    var elementDrawing = CreateImageSignatureForBody(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart, (TeoTagModel<(string, byte[])>)value);
    InsertImageSignatureAtTab(sdtBlocks, elementDrawing);
}

if (sdtBlockFooter.Any())
{
    var elementDrawing = CreateImageSignatureForHeader(footer, (TeoTagModel<(string, byte[])>)value);
    InsertImageSignatureAtTab(sdtBlockFooter, elementDrawing);
}

footer.Footer.Save();

Creating an Image
private Drawing CreateDrawingElement(string idOfPart, string tagKey) 
{
    return new Drawing(
     new DW.Inline(
         new DW.Extent() { Cx = 100000L, Cy = 102000L },
         new DW.EffectExtent()
         {
             LeftEdge = 0L,
             TopEdge = 0L,
             RightEdge = 0L,
             BottomEdge = 0L
         },
         new DW.DocProperties()
         {
             Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
             Name = $"Picture{tagKey}"
         },
         new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
             new A.GraphicFrameLocks()),
         new A.Graphic(
             new A.GraphicData(
                 new PIC.Picture(
                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties( new A.PictureLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true, NoChangeArrowheads = true },
                         new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                         {
                             Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                             Name = $"Picture{tagKey}"
                         },
                         new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                     new PIC.BlipFill(
                         new A.Blip(
                             new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                 new A.BlipExtension()
                                 {
                                     Uri =
                                        "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                 })
                         )
                         {
                             Embed = idOfPart,
                             CompressionState =A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                         },
                         new A.Stretch(
                             new A.FillRectangle())),
                     new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                         new A.Transform2D(
                             new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                             new A.Extents() { Cx = 100000L, Cy = 102000L }),
                         new A.PresetGeometry(
                             new A.AdjustValueList()
                         )
                         { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
             )
             { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
     )
     {
         DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
         DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
         DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
         DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
         EditId = "50D07946"
     });
}       

Creating an ImagePart
private Drawing CreateImageSignatureForBody(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, TeoTagModel<(string, byte[])> signatureTeoTag)
{
    if (signatureTeoTag.TagValue.Item2 == null) return null;

    ImagePartType imagePartType;
    if (ImagePartType.TryParse(signatureTeoTag.TagValue.Item1, out imagePartType))
    {
        ImagePart imagePart = mainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(imagePartType);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(signatureTeoTag.TagValue.Item2))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }

        var element = CreateDrawingElement(mainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), signatureTeoTag.TagKey);

        return element;
    }

    return null;
}

private Drawing CreateImageSignatureForHeader(FooterPart footerPart, TeoTagModel<(string, byte[])> signatureTeoTag)
{
    if (signatureTeoTag.TagValue.Item2 == null) return null;

    ImagePartType imagePartType;
    if (ImagePartType.TryParse(signatureTeoTag.TagValue.Item1, out imagePartType))
    {
        ImagePart imagePart = footerPart.AddImagePart(imagePartType,"rId999");
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(signatureTeoTag.TagValue.Item2))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }

        var element = CreateDrawingElement(footerPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), signatureTeoTag.TagKey);
        return element;
    }
    return null;
}

Insert Image
private void InsertImageSignatureAtTab(IEnumerable<SdtElement> sdtBlocks, Drawing signatureImage)
{
    if(sdtBlocks.Count() != 0)
    {
        foreach(var sdtBlock in sdtBlocks)
        {
            try
            {

                if (sdtBlock is SdtCell)
                {
                    var tableCell = sdtBlock.Descendants<TableCell>().FirstOrDefault();
                    var run = tableCell.Descendants<Run>().FirstOrDefault();
                    run.RemoveAllChildren<Drawing>();
                    run.Append(signatureImage);
                }
                else if (sdtBlock is SdtRun)
                {
                    sdtBlock.Descendants<SdtContentRun>().FirstOrDefault().Append(signatureImage);

                }
                else if(sdtBlock is SdtBlock) 
                {
                    sdtBlock.Descendants<SdtContentBlock>().FirstOrDefault().Append(signatureImage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Ошибка при добавление подписи: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


You may find the solution if you follow the process here.
